# How can I make this JavaScript code get executed when the BigPipe module is enabled?

Tags: javascript

I keep struggling with getting JavaScript executed when I need to target a DOM element that is added via the BigPipe module when I'm logged in on my Drupal site.

The following code runs when I'm not logged in, but it's never executed when I am logged in.

```js
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  Drupal.behavior.bpBlockTest = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('.my-block', context).once('bp-block-testing').each(function () {
        var $myBlock = $(this);
        var $addOn = $('<span>addOn</span>');
        $addOn.appendTo($myBlock);
      });
    }
  }

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2):

For the current Drupal version this is the correct way to run Javascript (including jQuery, Drupal and the new Drupal once library):

```
(function ($, Drupal, once) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      once('myCustomBehavior', 'input.myCustomBehavior', context).forEach(function (element) {
        // Apply the myCustomBehaviour effect to the elements only once.
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, once);
```

MODULE.libraries.yml or THEME.libraries.yml:

```
foobar:
  js:
    js/foobar.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/jquery
    - core/once
```

From https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

See also https://www.drupal.org/node/3158256

Comment: @BANO While this code is technically correct, there is currently an open bug related to this, https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3272693 where `context` is not as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Until [#3272693](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3272693) is fixed, the fix for this is to remove `context` from your once function or use `$.filter()`

```js
(function ($, Drupal, once) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // don't use context with once
      once('myBehavior', '.myBehavior').forEach(function (element) {});
      // or use filter
      $(context).filter('.myBehavior').once('myBehavior').forEach(function (element) {});
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, once);
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider the issue as a bug, BigPipe works as designed. But when using the module you might need to adjust custom JS code to run for each lazy-loaded part of the page separately. Your answer is helpful if you can't apply `.once` to elements inside of the block like the example in my answer. It's preferable to make it as granular as possible to avoid such problems.